# Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS Kickstart ignores all partitioning commands

Tags: 12.04, server, partitioning, kickstart

We need to use PXE netboot to deploy multiple identical Ubuntu 12.04 LTS servers.

I've tried various Kickstart config files and was ALWAYS thrown into the installer's partitioning screen. The automated installation runs OK until its partitioning part and then it stops prompting for Manual of Guided way. It does not matter if I use standard or alternative server CD's (we use amd64 architecture) - I always got the same results. 
I've also tried the same Kickstart configs with CD installation and installer acted the same way. Have anyone experienced the same installer's behaviour?

```
#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/Vancouver
#Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$j.nmHx6Z$i2MJ1qZQK2bcB58lp3aT./
#Initial user
user sa --fullname "System Administrator" --iscrypted --password $1$HPhjKlNS$fqwFah9e3IsSxdJMqaEf60
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use Web installation
url --url http://hostname.domain.com/ubuntu
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
#Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype ext2 --size 2048 --asprimary --ondisk sda
part /data --fstype ext4 --size 204800 --asprimary --ondisk sda
part / --fstype ext4 --size 51200 --ondisk sda
part /home --fstype ext4 --size 51200 --ondisk sda
part /var --fstype ext4 --size 102400 --ondisk sda
part swap --recommended --asprimary --ondisk sda
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
```

Comment: LP [#537421](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kickseed/+bug/537421): a little bit different but worth trying. Try without `--ondisk sda`.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion did not work. I've tried this before and tried again. As usual installer went to Manual or Guided partitioning screen. If at this point I do partitioning by hands - automated installation resumes normally. The final system has all settings I've requested in KS .cfg file. We have just one drive in all our test and production servers - so, it becomes /dev/sda device anyway.

Comment: [SOLVED] The Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS Kickstart automatic partitioning works ONLY with "/dev/sda" device. My first SATA hard drive was "/dev/sde" because of some USB cardreaders. I've disconnected them and installation went fine.

Comment: please place what "solved" in a answer, we don't use "solved" in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are two HDD inside Physical server and there are raid1 relation between them.raid1 setup is done through BIOS.
I am getting the same error "No root filesystem is defined".

Can someone share the ks.cfg for automated “ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64” OS  installation on physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Physical server and are in process of Automated “ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64” OS  installation on it.

There are two HDD for OS installation purpose and there are RAID1 relation between them. This setup has been done through BIOS.

The kickstart configuration file looks like this:

## Generated by Kickstart Configurator

## platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

## System language

lang en_US

## Language modules to install

langsupport en_US

## System keyboard

keyboard us

## System mouse

mouse

## System timezone

timezone Asia/Dili

## Root password

rootpw --iscrypted $1$Yl1QJyta$KzIT.kq3i9E5XaiQKcUJn/

## Initial user

user ankit --fullname "Ankit" --iscrypted --password $1$c6Yflpea$pi1QQ59/jgywmGwBv25z3/

## Reboot after installation

reboot

## Use text mode install

text

## Install OS instead of upgrade

install

## Use Web installation

url --url REPO

## System bootloader configuration

bootloader --location=mbr

## Clear the Master Boot Record

zerombr yes

## Partition clearing information

clearpart --all --initlabel

## Disk partitioning information

part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 100 --ondisk sda
part / --fstype ext4 --size 10000 --ondisk sda
part /var --fstype ext4 --size 10000 --ondisk sda
part swap --size 1024 --ondisk sdb

## System authorization infomation

auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5

## Network information

network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0

## Firewall configuration

firewall --enabled --trust=eth0 --http --ftp --ssh --telnet --smtp

## X Window System configuration information

xconfig --depth=8 --resolution=640x480 --defaultdesktop=GNOME

But I am getting the below error : "No root file system is defined"

Please suggest on this. Do we need to do any modification in kickstart configuration file.
Any help in this regard will be very helpful for us.

The automated Ubuntu OS installation is successful in Virtual Machine(VM) with the above ks.cfg (kickstart configuration file ) but failing in case of physical machine.
Please suggest on this and if possible provide the new ks.cfg file to resolve above problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajesh Prasad